# Using PCL with 2D Laser scanners

Tags: point-cloud-library, ros, point-clouds

I've been researching for a while now on creating a point cloud from laser scans, but I'm running into a few issues:

First of all, PCL doesn't have io support for hokuyo lasers, so I'm planning on using the hokuyoaist library for that.

The main problem I have is how to convert from 2D laser data to a point cloud (pointcloud2) so I can work with the PCL library. I am aware of some packages in ROS that do this, but I really don't want to get near to ROS doing this.

Thanks in advance,

Marwan

Comment: What do you want to do with the 2D data? Use it as-is for 2D purposes or for example combine multiple scans into a 3D scan?

Comment: @anderas The latter, combine multiple scans into a 3D scan

Comment: Assuming that you are using a 2D scanner on a PTU (or a similar setup): Do you have the current orientation of the PTU at each scan?

Comment: @anderas I have it mounted on top of a robot's head. I'm planning on changing pitch in small increments to change orientation. Since the laser scanner covers 270* degrees, I probably wont need to change yaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like (untested, but should get you going):

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <vector>

// Get Hokuyo data
int numberOfDataPoints = 0; // you need to fill this
std::vector<double> hokuyoDataX,hokuyoDataY;
for(int i=0;i<numberOfDataPoints;i++)
{
    hokuyoDataX.push_back(...); // you need to fill this for the x of point i
    hokuyoDataY.push_back(...); // you need to fill this for the y of point i
}

// Define new cloud object
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXY>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXY>);
cloud->is_dense = true; // no NaN and INF expected. 
cloud->width = hokuyoDataX.size();
cloud->height = 1;
cloud->points.resize(hokuyoDataX.size());
// Now fill the pointcloud
for(int i=0; i<hokuyoDataX.size(); i++)
{
    cloud->points[i].x = hokuyoDataX[i];
    cloud->points[i].y = hokuyoDataY[i];
}
```

Comment: If you know the structure of your data you may even set the cloud to the real height and width and get an organized point cloud. Having an organized point cloud boosts a lot of algorithms, some algorithms in the pcl are only for such clouds.